# Convert unsigned char audio to short

Tags: c++, c, audio, signal-processing

Trying to convert an `unsigned char` to a short. The data is Audio. My system is Little Endian. What I'm doing is this:

```
    short buf1[audio_size / 2];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < audio_size; i += 2) {
        if(i > audio_size) {
            break;
        }

        if(i + 1 > audio_size) {
            buf1[i] = audio_data[i] << 8;
        } else {
            buf1[i] = audio_data[i] << 8|audio_data[i + 1];
        }
    }
```

The result is bad audio and `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at `buf1[i] = info.data[i] << 8|info.data[i + 1];`

**Update:**

Audio sampling rate is 8000. 1 Channel. 16bit PCMU mulaw.

Comment: the buffer has a size `audio_size / 2`, but you index into it up to the `audio_size-1` index so you run into buffer overflow, probably. I suspect you should use `i/2` as index instead of `i`.

Comment: I upgrade above from "probably" to "guaranteed".

Comment: @Yunnosch yeah :) I was saying probably just in case audio_size would be 0 or 1 ...

Comment: @OlivierSohn I take back the "guaranteed" and draw my hat for your paranoia. Please understand that this is a compliment.

Comment: @Yunnosch on the other hand, a stereo audio buffer of size 0 or 1 is not very usefull :) so in case the program was attempting to do something usefull, then guaranteed was probably the right thing here!

Comment: Why the tag spam? Which language is it, C or C++? Where's the [mcve]? Input, output, expected result? Read [ask], debugging requests shall have **all required** information in the question. Oh, and you don#t convert any types.

Comment: Language is C and C++, per tags. Yes projects can simultaneously use both. Example is provided. Input output? You want the binary dump of audio bytes? lol really? The input audio data's features are included in the question. Nice case of cherry picking though, appreciate the downvote too.

Comment: You should probably use `unsigned short` instead of `short`

Comment: I have to use short because that's the type required by an api I'm using. I tried using unsigned short anyway and then used reinterpret_cast to short but the audio sound from that is still bad

Comment: in the C language, to convert a unsigned char to a unsigned short: `unsigned char originalValue;   short modifiedValue;   modifiedValue = (short) originalValue;`

Answer (score 2):

The buffer has a size `audio_size / 2`, but you index into it up to the `audio_size-1` index so you run into buffer overflow.

You should use `i/2` as index instead of `i`.

Also, another bug in this loop is that

```
if(i + 1 > audio_size)
```

should be replaced by

```
if(i + 1 >= audio_size)
```

This is another reason for buffer overflow, but this time in the other (source) buffer

Comment: Thanks that solved the bad access. What about the conversion? Any reason why I'm getting bad data back?

Comment: @Seph that's a separate concern which deserves a new question of its own, where you would explain from what format to which format you want to convert, and what you observe, etc...

Comment: @Seph Btw, when you encounter a bug like that, I recommend you learn how to use a debugger: that will empower you, and you will be a lot more independant (you won't have to ask here on every bug you have)

Comment: Look thanks for catching those bugs, but don't leap from the bridge into assuming my competence level. I hastily posted that code after after trying other iterations. The main question is about converting audio data, not off by 1 or overflow errors. Feel like your hijacking this question and turning it something else. Worse, I'm just some "noob" because I posted some code in frustration.

Comment: @Seph I didn't mean to sound like that, I'm sorry if it hurted you. But when I read `The result is bad audio and EXC_BAD_ACCESS at buf1[i] = info.data[i] << 8|info.data[i + 1];` I kind of understand that the main point of the question is buffer overflow issues. And that's 2 totally separate issues, stackoverflow questions should concentrate on one issue at a time.

Comment: I understand but getting patronized about using a debugger when I've been programming for decades (maybe not in c) rubbed me the wrong way. SO question also shouldn't be about "debug my code" which is would be the result if I split this into a separate question. The code example just happened to contain hastily put together bugs and you caught and I'm grateful for improving the question. Removing the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` part would remove the context of your answer which you've earned points on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176454/discussion-between-seph-and-olivier-sohn).

Comment: You have a point, SO question also shouldn't be about "debug my code". I didn't mean to patronize, just give some advice to someone who is not very experienced in C, obviously (an experienced C programmer would have caught these errors early on). I know it's not easy to learn a new language, a new way to develop, I myself had this experience when getting to know Haskell last year, and I remember very well how uneasy I felt, because I was suddenly feeling I didn't know anything, despite my long years of C / C++. So I understand what you feel, but that's just the learning curve I guess.